# Stylus not work image-size(path)

Tags: stylus

```
image-size(path)
```

Returns the width and height of the image found at path. Lookups are performed in the same manner as `@import`, altered by the paths setting.

Example:

```
width(img)
    return image-size(img)[0]

  height(img)
    return image-size(img)[1]

  image-size('tux.png')
  // => 405px 250px
```

How to get the height and insert it into the css property?

For example:

```
.qwert
    width image-width(test.jpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.qwert
  width image-size('test.jpg')[0]
```